# Rackspace cloud files upload directly mobile client

Tags: android, ios, mobile, rackspace-cloudfiles

I know about FormPost:

> FormPost lets you offer your website audience a way to upload objects
>   to your Cloud Files account through a web form.

It work perfectly for website.

Is there a way to upload the file using the signature from mobile app, as in the likeness of tempurl download file?
Without providing mobile application users my account API-key.
Wherein the limit the max files size and max count file upload is on similarity using the method FormPost

Comment: just use parse.com ?

Comment: @JoeBlow - if I'm not mistaken there storage a limit 20 GB

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the answer your are looking for but I solve this problem by:

1) mobile app post files to my web app.
2) my web app (which is already on Rackspace Servers) deals with the files, uploading them to Rackspace Files.

Advantages of that is that:

- Only my app knows about my API-key
- I could store file metadata (size, user, etc) into my MySQL database, instead of just having info about the container and file Id.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but it is too primitive